# How to separate an input on python into different lists?

Tags: python, list, input

I have a code in which I require 3 different inputs to be put into separate lists. Currently I have 3 lists set up:

```
A = []
B = []
C = []
```

I also currently have 3 different inputs, one for each list, and I wish to combine these inputs into one input, separating each factor of this by a comma or semicolon.

For example:

```
Apple,365,rope
```

Using python, how would I separate each factor in the input so they can be put into different lists?

I have tried searching for how to separate using an input but this has not worked as I do not know exactly what the input will be.

Comment: what structure is the input?  For example is it a string `"Apple,365,rope"`, a tuple ('Apple',365, 'rope')`, etc.

Comment: "Combine inputs into one input while separating each factor" doesn't make sense per se. Provide any relevant code, and more explanation of what you've tried, what your input looks like, what your output looks like, and what determines the output's appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input is on the command line using the `input()` function, you can do the following:

```
A = []
B = []
C = []

# let's say you input "Apple,365,rope"
my_input = input()

# we split it on each commma into a list -> ["Apple", "365","rope"]
split_input_list = myinput.split(',')

# finally we put each input into the respective list
A.append(split_input_list[0])
B.append(split_input_list[1])
C.append(split_input_list[2])
```

Comment: You assign to `A[0]` three times in a row. Did you mean `A[0]`, `B[0]`, `C[0]`? Additionally, you would have to use `append()`, since there is no element `0` in an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = []
B = []
C = []

# if string
your_input = "Apple,365,rope"
your_input = your_input.split(",")
A = [your_input[0]]
B = [your_input[1]]
C = [your_input[2]]

print A, B, C

# if tuple
your_input = ("Apple", "365" , "rope")
A = [your_input[0]]
B = [your_input[1]]
C = [your_input[2]]

print A, B, C
```

Comment: I would recommend against masking the built-in `input`.